# Getting data from multiple urls (looped) in Python

Tags: python, loops, urllib

I ran this code to get 31 urls, which all give me 24 bins with a number behind it.

```
eventurl = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/"
for dag in range(1, 32):
    print(eventurl + str(dag))
```

I now want to use the data out of all the urls that are printed after running this code. I want to specify the data to get the numbers behind the bins I was talking about earlier. When I use 1 url (I used 2017/1/1 as example below) I run this code:

```
eventurl = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/1/"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(eventurl)
data = data.read().decode()
events = data.split("# bin\tvalue")
nevents = [d.split("\t")[1] for d in events[1].strip().split("\n")]
nevents = list(map(int, nevents))
```

And I get 24 numbers I use in a graph later on. If I try this:

```
eventurl = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/"
for dag in range(1, 32):
    print(eventurl + str(dag))

data = urllib.request.urlopen(eventurl + str(dag))
data = data.read().decode()

events = data.split("# bin\tvalue")
nevents = [d.split("\t")[1] for d in events[1].strip().split("\n")]
print(nevents)
```

Then only the last 24 bins appear (2017/1/31).

Can anyone help me so that I get all the bins from 2017/1/1 until 2017/1/31?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just got an indenting problem:

```
eventurl = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/"
for dag in range(1, 32):
    print(eventurl + str(dag))

    data = urllib.request.urlopen(eventurl + str(dag))
    data = data.read().decode()

    events = data.split("# bin\tvalue")
    nevents = [d.split("\t")[1] for d in events[1].strip().split("\n")]
    print(nevents)
```

Comment: When I run this it returns "unexpected indent"

Comment: I literally copied your code and it doesn't work..? I checked all the indenting

Comment: What is the exact error? When I tried the code, but with a deliberate indentation error, python told me which line had the wrong indentation.

Comment: it first prints all the urls and then for every line (from data = urllib.request.urlopen(eventurl + str(dag)) until nevents = [d.split("\t")[1] for d in events[1].strip().split("\n")] unexpected indent

Comment: You may have to use your ide to format the code. Copy the code from my answer and paste it into your ide. Then unindent the lines from the first `print` to the last `print`. Then re-indent just those lines again so that your ide will choose the same indent for all those lines.

Comment: I use python 3 in `Thonny`. I've just been reading up and others say that python 2 may be more picky.

Comment: I use 3.6.3 in Terminal (Apple), might that be a problem?

Comment: Could be. The thing I don't understand is why some of the code runs and then you get multiple `unexpected indent`?

Comment: My answer works in both Thonny (python 3.6.1) and Pycharm (python 2.7.5)

Comment: Do you have IDLE on your Apple?